# Como resolver o problema de validação de data - calendar - PrimeFaces?

Tags: java, java-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

Ao carregar a data num calendar (PrimeFaces) carrega normalmente:

Código:

```
<p:outputLabel value="Data de Nascimento" for="data-nascimento" />
<p:calendar id="data-nascimento" locale="pt" mask="99/99/9999"
            value="#{solicitacaoRHBean.itemEdicao.dataNascimento}"
            required="true" navigator="true"
            requiredMessage="Data de Nascimento é obrigatório">
</p:calendar>
```

Mas no momento de validar/persistir a informação dá mensagem de erro dizendo que a data não é uma data válida.

Como resolver esta questão?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Receio que o problema esteja no "mask", como o próprio atributo aponta, é apenas uma máscara. Tente utilizar o atributo "pattern" no lugar de mask: `pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"`.

Comment: Caso busque outra alternativa creio que seria mais viável utilizar o Bean Validation do Hibernate para fazer as validações. Segue exemplo: http://blog.caelum.com.br/java-ee-6-comecando-com-bean-validation/

Comment: Patrick, eu troquei o mask por pattern e funcionou obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o `locale="pt"` funcionar, você precisa [adicionar um javascript](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/wiki/PrimeFacesLocales) na sua página, pois por padrão, ele é apenas em inglês.

Mask é apenas uma máscara, não a formatação em si. Contudo, você pode forçar o padrão brasileiro utilizando o atributo e valor `pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"`.

Comment: Ok vou pesquisar.